# Streaming weekdays with scala

Tags: scala, streaming

I am fairly new with play, and I would like to develop a function that randomly return some weekdays asynchronously. My method would ideally have the signature:

```
def randomlyEndingStream: Future[Option[String]]
```

Any tips on how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: Does when the day is returned need to be random as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
def maybeGiveSomeWeekday:Future[Option[String]] = {
    Future.successful(Random.nextInt(8) match{
      case 0 => Some("Monday")
      case 1 => Some("Tuesday")
      case 2 => Some("Wednesday")
      case 3 => Some("Thursday")
      case 4 => Some("Friday")
      case 5 => Some("Saturday")
      case 6 => Some("Sunday")
      case 7 => None
    })
  }
```